# Quick help on adjusting/moving key value pairs on an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

assuming i have an object

```
let data = { info_0: 'abc', info_1: 'def', info_2: 'ghi' }
```

and i received a value of 1 from a user input. I need to..

1. Search & delete info_1 from the object
2. Move/rename info_2 into info_1
3. Should be dynamic

You get the idea, you receive index from a user. Delete that key-value pair from the object and adjust/move every key inside so it looks like an array from 0 to X. (in this case info_0 to info_x)

I have a looong solution of for, if's & obj keys loop. but i am trying to learn a few shortcuts. very much appreciated for the help

**EDIT:**
object may also contain a mix of various keys eg:
client_x, charges_x, description_x etc etc

```
{ info_0  : '', info_1  : '', client_0  : '', client_1  : '', client_2  : '', descpription_0 : '' }
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using an array instead with `Array#splice` for removal?

Comment: If you use this, you'd have to update every key after `info_x`. The order of keys will be messed up. Use an array.

Comment: hi guys, I'm sorry but there is nothing i can do for the object. and believe me it is the best design if the object is like that. problem is client wanted an unforeseeable feature that i have to resort to this.
object may also contain various keys eg: client_x, graph_x, charges_0 etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just shift the values of the properties by 1

```js
let data = {
    info_0: 'abc',
    info_1: 'def',
    info_2: 'ghi',
    info_3: 'jkl',
    info_4: 'mno',
    info_5: 'pqr'
  },
  input = document.querySelector("#index"),
  button = document.querySelector("#remove"),
  output = document.querySelector("#output");

button.addEventListener("click", () => removeItem(+input.value));
refreshOutput();

function removeItem(index) {
  if (isNaN(index) || index < 0) return;
  index = Math.floor(index);
  while (data["info_" + index] !== undefined) {
    data["info_" + index] = data["info_" + ++index];
  }
  refreshOutput();
}

function refreshOutput() {
  output.textContent = JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

```html
<input id="index" type="number" placeholder="index" />
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

You could also use the `delete` operator (which is very inefficient)

```js
let data = {
    info_0: 'abc',
    info_1: 'def',
    info_2: 'ghi',
    info_3: 'jkl',
    info_4: 'mno',
    info_5: 'pqr'
  },
  input = document.querySelector("#index"),
  button = document.querySelector("#remove"),
  output = document.querySelector("#output");

button.addEventListener("click", () => removeItem(+input.value));
refreshOutput();

function removeItem(index) {
  if (isNaN(index) || index < 0) return;
  index = Math.floor(index);
  while (("info_" + index) in data) {
    data["info_" + index] = data["info_" + ++index];
  }
  delete data["info_" + index];
  refreshOutput();
}

function refreshOutput() {
  output.textContent = JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

```html
<input id="index" type="number" placeholder="index" />
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Or you could just use an array and `Array#splice`

```js
let data = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr'],
  input = document.querySelector("#index"),
  button = document.querySelector("#remove"),
  output = document.querySelector("#output");

button.addEventListener("click", () => removeItem(+input.value));
refreshOutput();

function removeItem(index) {
  if (isNaN(index) || index < 0) return;
  data.splice(Math.floor(index), 1);
  refreshOutput();
}

function refreshOutput() {
  output.textContent = JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

```html
<input id="index" type="number" placeholder="index" />
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: wow! the first solution using while loop is the shortest and efficient one. sweet! thank you. I should use/practice while loops on my projects more

Comment: I still think you should use arrays instead of objects.